# Linux Running executable by linking prebuilt libraries from terminal

Tags: linux, terminal

I have a folder containing executable (named sd) and also some prebuilt libraries like libbortqt-6.9-qt2.3.so , libpng.so.2 etc . When I run program sd by typing ./sd in terminal , it give me error
 ::: libborqt-6.9-qt2.3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

can anyone suggest me how to solve it

Comment: `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ./sd`

Answer (score 0):

Try doing

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.
./sd
```